# Is there any AWS support for Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, aws-sdk

As I can see a very little community support for parse, AWS javascript SDK is not supported on cloud code. If anybody can suggest anything to use AWS services from cloud code it will be a great help.

Comment: Issue get solved when we migrated parse server onto our own environment.

Answer (score 1):

As Parse Cloud Code is based off the v8 Javascript engine, and does not run Node.js, so no, you will not be able to run the AWS SDK directly.  If you need the AWS SDK, I'd recommend moving your Cloud Code over to Node, which you can find out more about [here](http://blog.parse.com/learn/using-node-js-with-parse/).